# equivalence of weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\mu,\mu_1,\mu_2,...$ be finite measures on the Borel sets of a metric space $\Omega$. I want to proof that:

if

for every open set $A$ such that $\mu( \partial(A))=0$ we have $\mu_n(A)\to\mu(A)$

then

$\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$

I know that weak convergence is equivalent to:

for every borel set $A\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ such that $\mu(\partial(A))=0$ we have $\mu_n(A)\to\mu(A)$

What I tried is defining the good sets

$\mathscr{C}:=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$: if $\mu(\partial(A))=0$ then $\mu_n(A)\to\mu(A)$}

and tried to proof it is a $\sigma-$algebra, so that by the good sets principle $\mathscr{C}=\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$. I proved $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under complements but i couldn't proof it is closed under countable unions. I tried making it a disjoint union but the proof still eludes me.

Any help or hints?

Comment: Do you know Portemanteau theorem or do you want to have a specific different proof?

Comment: Thank you. I had not think I could follow the proof for Portemanteau's theorem and see if I can alter it for my needs

Comment: In my version for Portmanteau this equivalence should be proven, you can check it in Klenke Probability Theory (pdf is available on springer for uni students) in I believe either chapter 13 or 14 :) Let me know if it works

Comment: I believe It is not in Klenke Probability Theory for open sets with boundary measure zero, just for measurable sets with boundary measure zero. But anyway the hint worked!

Comment: But this should be enough if you have the Borel Sigma Algebra, i.e. Klenkes Version is stronger no?

Comment: it is stronger. I was trying to prove the weaker statement implies the stronger one.